# Designate two files from a list using comboboxes on each list element. Is there a better way?

Tags: website-design

I've got a dialog in my web application which requires the user to designate two files from a list of many using a combobox associated with the file. One file must be designated as "type 1" and the second file must be designated "type 2" before continuing. Processing will happen on the two files chosen.

At the moment the dialog looks something like this:

[image]

This feels too 'busy' to me having a combo box on every file box. Any suggestions for improving this selection method?

Comment: "One file must be designated as "type 1" and the second file must be designated "type 2" before continuing. Processing will happen on the two files chosen." This sounds a little specific and confusing. Can break out the user goals in terms of possible actions? i.e. what is the user trying to do, and what options constraints exist.

Comment: Please provide details.  Do your users need to see information about the files before selecting? Or do they know the files they want, but perhaps want to double-check the information after selecting? Or do they not care about file details at all?  Does this list already exist for another purpose (where this type-selection functionality is laid over it)? Or is it not constrained to work with a list at all?  Are users more likely to select file, then type? Or type, then file?  What platform will this be on? Do your users have any salient characteristics?

Comment: are there just 2 possible types?

Comment: I realize now my question could have used some more detail, but my selected answer is just what I needed. To answer some of your questions, the user wouldn't see any file details, just the name. And yes, there are only two file types in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like what coops suggested...

Present two listboxes on the screen, on labeled "type 1" and the other "type 2".
Start with all of your files in the "type 1" listbox.
When any file is picked in that listbox, move all of the selected files to the "type 2" listbox.
Only enable the submit button when one entry in each listbox is selected.

You could even wrap the process in friendly prose, modifying the text as each file is selected...

[image: Before the user select anything]

...

[image: After the user select a file]

Just remember that if you go with this kind of single-page-app approach, you need to code a way for your user to de-select their previously selected "type-1" file, resetting the interface to its original state.

Answer (score 0):

Only display a single combo box for Type 1 when the page loads. When a user selects type 1, only then display the type 2 combo box.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Coops.  This answer is very short. Can you explain why you think this would be an optimal solution?  For example, you might answer: what makes responsive disclosure a better solution than responsive enabling?  Or how would this solution work if you also needed to see details about the files?